# struck out the one time he was at bat - meaning

Tags: meaning

> How did Timmy do yesterday?
>   He struck out **the one time** he was at bat.
>   Aw. That's too bad.
>   I know. He did his darndest though.

I can't understand that line I put in a bold-type font.

Comment: The single instance that he came to bat he struck out.

Comment: Or, "The only time he was at bat, he struck out!" Or, "He got up to bat only once and struck out." Or, "He was at bat only once, but he struck out."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be in the context of a baseball game.

Over the whole game, Timmy had once chance at bat, where he struck out.

What it's highlighting, is that he didn't have multiple turns at bat.